# Appium Unable to start emulator on MAC

Tags: android, appium

Hi I am very new to appium and I thought I did everything correct to do this. Appium is giving me this error:
error: 
Unable to start Emulator: PANIC: HOME is defined but could not find .ini file in $HOME/.android/avd
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

I followed these directions to setup:
Download Android SDK
https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Extract Android SDK to /usr/local/adt/
unzip -qo adt-bundle-*.zip -d /usr/local/adt

Set ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/adt/sdk

Add ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME to sh profile (in order not to set them every time)
echo "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/adt/sdk" >> ~/.bash_profile

Install Android build and platform tools
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the name your avd the same as the file.

[AVD Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2OAl.png)

The files in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd in this case will look like 4_7_WXGA_API22.avd and 4_7_WXGA_API22.ini.